# Test if my device is discoverable on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to test if my android device is discoverable before sending the intent that prompts the user to turn it on, what do I do?

the intent is as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
intent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 30);
startActivityForResult(intent, idBlueToothDiscoveryRequest);
```

Comment: Why not just make it discoverable with `BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()` that way you don't need to check.

Comment: I think there's a difference in being dicoverable, and discovering other devices. BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery() starts discovery, but I don't think that makes my device discoverable for other devices.

Comment: In future can you post the solution as an answer rather than an edit to the question.

Answer (score 16):

I found out:

```
if(mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    intent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 30);
    startActivityForResult(intent, idBlueToothDiscoveryRequest);
}
```